# Weight Paint isn't painting smoothly?

Tags: weight-painting

so I'm planning to weight paint a tentacle. I chose one of the bones on the tentacles and started on weight painting. I found something wrong though... When I weight paint, sometimes it shows, sometimes nothing happens. How do i solve this? I actually tried subdividing the tentacles into 10++ cuts. It solved the problem, but it become very very laggy. Anyone knows how to solve this problem? [Weight paint problem](https://youtu.be/66K3VMlc33g)

Answer (score 1):

I see that you're trying to paint between vertices, you can't, if you want the painting to be more subtle you need to subdivide your object. And of course you also need to use the good brush strength (you can mainly use the *Draw* brush in *Mix* or *Subtract* mode, <kbd>F</kbd> to change the brush radius, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to change its strength, you can also use the *Blur* brush to smooth).

Weight painting is used to give a value between 0 (blue) and 1 (red) to your vertices, 0 meaning the selected vertex group (in the *Vertex Groups* list) has 0% influence on this vertex, 1 (red) meaning it has 100% influence on this vertex.

Which doesn't mean that this vertex can't be part of other vertex groups by the way, several groups can have a weight of 1, which means they will equally influence this vertex.

So you can't paint edges or faces, only vertices.

If you open the *N panel > Item > Vertex Weight*, you can select a vertex and see what group this vertex is part of and how much weight this group has on this vertex:

[image]

Also, good thing to know, if you want to paint through, disable the *Front Faces Only* and *Front-face Falloff* options and enable *Projected*:

[image]

Comment: But that doesn't solves the problem though. Have you watched the video? I want to weight paint the tentacles smoothly but it doesn't lets me does that.

Comment: I see that you're trying to paint between vertices, you can't, if you want the painting to be more subtle you need to subdivide your object. Of course you also need to use the good brush strength